# proof that for a square matrix $A$ it holds $\ker\left(A\right)^{\perp}\subseteq Im\left(A^{\top}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that for a square matrix $A$ it holds that $Im\left(A^{\top}\right)=\ker\left(A\right)^{\perp}$ I already proved that $Im\left(A^{\top}\right)\subseteq\ker\left(A\right)^{\perp}$ by showing that for $v\in Im\left(A^{\top}\right)$ and for every $u\in\ker\left(A\right)$ it holds
$\left\langle v,u\right\rangle =\left\langle A^{\top}x,u\right\rangle =\left(A^{\top}x\right)^{\top}u=x^{\top}Au=x^{\top}\cdot0=0$ (where $Ax=v$) but i cannot seem to find a way to prove that $\ker\left(A\right)^{\perp}\subseteq Im\left(A^{\top}\right)$

Comment: if you've shown that $\text{Im }\left(A^{\top}\right)\subseteq\ker\left(A\right)^{\perp}$, then it suffices to show that they have the same dimensions.  $\dim \text{Im }\left(A^{\top}\right)= \text{rank }A^T=\text{rank }A = n-\dim \ker A$ by rank-nullity.  Now make an argument about $\dim \big((\ker A)^\perp\big)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in \text{Ker}(A)^{\perp}$.  Since the entire space is always a direct sum of a subspace and its orthogonal complement, there is a decomposition $x = u + v$ with $u\in \text{Im}(A^{\top})$, $v\in \text{Im}(A^{\top})^{\perp}$ and $u\perp v$.  Since $v\perp \text{Im}(A^{\top})$, you have $\langle z, Av\rangle = \langle A^{\top} z, v \rangle = 0$ for all $z$.  Therefore $Av = 0$, i.e. $v\in \text{Ker}(A)$.  But $x\perp \text{Ker}(A)$ so $x\perp v$!  Therefore $0 = \langle x, v \rangle = \langle u + v, v\rangle = \langle u, v\rangle + \langle v, v \rangle = \langle v, v \rangle$ (remember that $u \perp v$).  So $v = 0$.